# How to call method written in VB.NET from C# with optional arguments

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a method written in VB.NET. It looks like this:

```
Shared Sub SomeMethod(ByVal Id As Guid, 
                      Optional ByVal str1 As String = "foo", 
                      Optional ByVal str2 As String = "")
```

I want to call this method from C# 3.0 and I want it to use its default arguments. I tried passing `System.Reflection.Missing.Value`, but I cannot cast it as String.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, in C#3 you simply have to pass all parameters. C#4 will have optional and named parameters.

You could off course create a few overloaded variations, but that is only an approximation.

Comment: +1. This is exactly what the VB.Net compiler does anyway - it simply automatically inserts the default values for any missing values when it compiles the caller.

Comment: @MarkJ, yes, but in Fx4 the optional values are also in the metadata, I just verified with VS2010. C# uses the opt values from VB just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Without using C# 4.0 (which adds support for optional parameters) you can't use them; if you run your code through FxCop you will see Optional parameters specifically flagged for their inability to be consumed by C#.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to retrieve optional parameters' values you can use reflection, this information is stored in custom attribute at corresponding parameter

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He wants to do `SomeMethod(someGUID, "Some String")` from C# where the VB Method Signature is as he indicated. Something that's not possible on C# < 4.0